# Selenium, Python, ChromeOptions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Can you tell me where I find the arguments list in `chromeOptions`?

Example:

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

I need all possible arguments and know what each one does.

Comment: Check this if it helps - https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/